# The Solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ of $a^0+a^1+a^2+\cdots+a^{b-1}+a^b=c^d$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a\ge2, b\ge2,c\ge2,d\ge2\in\mathbb N$.

Also, let $N(a,b,c,d)$ be the number of the solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ of

$$a^0+a^1+a^2+\cdots+a^{b-1}+a^b=c^d.$$

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Are the followings true?
>
> $(1)$  $N(a,b,c,2)=2$.
>
> $(2)$ $N(a,b,c,3)=1$.
>
> $(3)$ There exist $d$ such that $N(a,b,c,d)=0$.
>
> $(4)$ For every $d\ge2$, $N(a,b,c,d)$ is finite.

**Example** :
$${3}^{0}+{3}^1+{3}^2+3^3+3^4={11}^2,$$
$${7}^{0}+{7}^1+{7}^2+7^3={20}^2,$$
$${18}^{0}+{18}^1+{18}^2=7^3.$$

**Motivation** : I have not been able to find the other solutions even by using computer (I hope I don't miss anything). I don't have any good idea for answering these questions. I would like to know any relevant references. Can anyone help?

Comment: See also the link to the [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58697/a-geometric-series-equalling-a-power-of-an-integer) question

Comment: @IvanLoh: Thank you very much for your information.